# SQL query inside another query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

| total | user | wallet | storagesummary | chain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | user1 | wallet1 | 2 | 1 |
| 30 | user1 | wallet1 | 4 | 1 |
| 8 | user1 | wallet2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | user2 | wallet3 | 3 | 1 |
| 41 | user2 | wallet3 | 4 | 3 |

And this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Type1, Type2, n... columns are a combination of **storagesummary** and **chain**

Just for the sake of example: if **storagesummary** == 2 and **chain** == 1, then it's gonna be Type1.

I tried something like this, but I don't think it's the best approach and I dunno what to do with the user/wallet columns:

```
SELECT (SELECT total from MyTable where storagesummary = 2 and chain == 1) as Total Type1 Count,
       (SELECT total from MyTable where storagesummary = 4 and chain == 1) as Total Type2 Count,
      .......
```

I cant' figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could use a bit of conditional aggregation to pivot that.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(t.user, ' / ', t.wallet) AS "User Wallet Address"
, SUM(CASE 
      WHEN t.storagesummary = 2 AND t.chain = 1 
        THEN t.total
      ELSE 0
      END) AS "Total Type1"
, SUM(CASE 
      WHEN t.storagesummary = 4 AND t.chain = 3
        THEN t.total 
      WHEN t.storagesummary = 1 AND t.chain = 1
        THEN t.total
      ELSE 0
      END) AS "Total Type2"
, SUM(CASE 
      WHEN t.storagesummary IN(2,5) AND t.chain >= 2 
        THEN t.total
      ELSE 0
      END) AS "Total Type3"
FROM MyTable t
GROUP BY t.user, t.wallet
ORDER BY t.user, t.wallet
```

Not sure if you need `SUM` or `MAX` though.
And the logic in the `CASE`'s will needs corrections.
But if you get the concept, then you'll understand what to change.